# Powershell5 Compact code by combining foreach, begin, process, and replace command

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Can I get the same results with less code?
The code searches sample.bat for the strings AROUND LINE {1-9999} and LINE2 {1-9999} and replaces {1-9999} with the {line number} the code is on.

sample.bat:

```
AROUND LINE 262
LINE2 1964
```

Old code:

```
gc $env:temp\sample.bat | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
  $_ -replace "AROUND LINE \d*", "AROUND LINE $lc";
  $lc += 1
} | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $env:temp\results.bat
(gc $env:temp\results.bat) | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
  $_ -replace "LINE2 \d*", "LINE2 $lc";
  $lc += 1
} | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $env:temp\results.bat
```

Current code:

```
(gc $env:temp\sample.bat) | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
  $_ -replace "AROUND LINE \d*", "AROUND LINE $lc";
  $lc += 1
} | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
  $_ -replace "LINE2 \d*", "LINE2 $lc";
} | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $env:temp\sample.bat
```

Expected results:

```
AROUND LINE 1
LINE2 2
```

Actual results:

```
AROUND LINE 1
LINE2 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work with a single regex:

```
gc $env:temp\sample.bat | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
  $_ -replace '(?<=AROUND LINE |LINE2 )\d+', $lc++
} | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii $env:temp\results.bat
```

<sup>Note that I'm using `'...'` (single quotes) rather than `"..."` (double quotes) to enclose the regex, which is preferable to rule out potential confusion arising from PowerShell performing string expansion (interpolation) first.

`$lc++` returns the current `$lc` value and increments it by `1` afterwards, obviating the need for the `$lc += 1` statement.

Also, I've replaced `Out-File` with `Set-Content`, as they're functionally the same for saving *strings*, but the latter is faster.

Finally, to match *one or more digits*, use `\d+` rather than `\d*`.</sup>

A note on `$_ -replace '(?<=AROUND LINE |LINE2 )\d+', $lc++`:

- Regex `(?<=AROUND LINE |LINE2 )\d+` uses a look-behind assertion (`(?<=...)` to look for either (`|`) string `AROUND LINE`  or string `LINE2` before one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`).

  - The look-behind assertion is by design not considered part of the match, so that the substring getting replaced is limited to the run of digits, i.e., the *number only*.
- `$lc++` is the replacement operand: it returns the current value of variable `$lc` and increments its value *afterwards*; note that even though `$lc` is a *number* (`[int]`), PowerShell automatically converts it to a string for the replacement.

---

Generally, though, you can simply *chain* `-replace` operations:

```
# ...
$_ -replace 'AROUND LINE \d+', "AROUND LINE $lc" -replace 'LINE2 \d+', "LINE2 $lc"
++$lc
# ...
```